# What do you think about OpenFire?

Tags: xmpp, real-time, openfire

Have you developed for OpenFire (http://www.igniterealtime.org/)?
How has your experience? pros/cons/comments, please.

I'm evaluation several technologies now, and want to know what the community thinks about OpenFire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried Openfire for a chat and message distribution project.

I really liked it at first. The documentation was good, the admin tool was good and the installation was easy.

But we could not make it perform. For some reason the login-process took a looooong time.

Also I have the impression that the project is dying.

We ended up with ejabberd, which works well and was also easy to set up.